# Query MVC controller with Ajax POST then redirect with a model

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Let's say that I have data that has a complicated format (a list of object) that I want to post to an MVC controller, and then I want this controller to redirect me to the page i want with the model it generated. Just like a POST request from a regular form would do.

Instead, when I do this angular request with angular:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/user/search',
            data: $scope.dataToSearch
        }).success(function() {
                // what do put here ?
        })
        .error(function() {

        });
```

- the controller successfully receives the data
- the controller successfully generates the model I want
- the controller returns "View("viewWanted", model") but it DOESN'T redirect.

All I receive is a status code 200, and the raw html of the page I wanted without redirecting me to this actual page. The thing is, if I do "window.location" on success, my controller won't generate the model because I have to post the data.

In conclusion, how to post then redirect like with a regular form, but with using Ajax/Angular/Javascript in general ? Thanks.

Comment: Normally if you are using Angular you are creating a SPA so you wouldn't perform redirects. You should modify your controller to instead return json for the results, which would then be bound to a table using a $scope property

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`Angular promises`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for return and wait the success request. So, you need more control from controllers, [`Restangular`](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) is better for this.